# showing shapes (1,400) and (10000,10) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 10000 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to run this machine learning code:

```py
import numpy as np, sys
from keras.datasets import mnist
np.random.seed(1)

(x_train, y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnist.load_data()

images,labels=(x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000,28*28)/255, y_train[0:1000])

one_hot_labels = np.zeros((len(labels),10))
for i,l in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][l]=1
labels = one_hot_labels

test_images= x_test.reshape(len(x_test),28*28)/255
test_labels = np.zeros((len(y_test),10))
for i,l in enumerate(y_test):
    test_labels[i][l]=1

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh2deriv(output):
    return 1 -(output**2)

def softmax(x):
    temp=np.exp(x)
    return temp /np.sum(temp, axis=1, keepdims=True)

alpha, iterations = (2,300)
pixels_per_image, num_labels = (784,10)
batch_size=128
input_rows=28
input_cols=28
kernel_rows=3
kernel_cols=3
num_kernels=16

hidden_size=((input_rows-kernel_rows)* (input_cols-kernel_cols)) * num_kernels

kernels = 0.02 * np.random.random((kernel_rows*kernel_cols, num_kernels))-0.01

weights_1_2 = 0.2 * np.random.random((hidden_size, num_labels))-0.01

def get_image_section(layer, row_from, row_to, col_from, col_to):
    section=layer[:,row_from: row_to, col_from: col_to]
    return section.reshape(-1, 1, row_to-row_from, col_to-col_from)

for j in range(iterations):
    correct_cnt=0
    for i in range(int(len(images)/batch_size)):
        batch_start, batch_end=((i*batch_size),((i+1)*batch_size))
        layer_0=images[batch_start:batch_end]
        layer_0=layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0],28,28)
        layer_0.shape
        
        sects=list()
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
                sect=get_image_section(layer_0,
                                      row_start,
                                      row_start+kernel_rows,
                                      col_start,
                                      col_start+kernel_cols)
                sects.append(sect)

        expanded_input=np.concatenate(sects,axis=1)
        es= expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input=expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1],-1)
        
        kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
        dropout_mask=np.random.randint(2,size=layer_1.shape)
        layer_1 *=dropout_mask*2
        layer_2=softmax(np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2))
        
        for k in range(batch_size):
            labelset=labels[batch_start+k:batch_start+k+1]
            _inc=int(np.argmax(layer_2[k:k+1])==
                    np.argmax(labelset))
            correct_cnt += _inc
        
        layer_2_delta=(labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2)\
                        / (batch_size * layer_2.shape[0])
        layer_1_delta=layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)*\
                        tanh2deriv(layer_1)
        layer_1_delta *=dropout_mask
        weights_1_2 += alpha*layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        l1d_reshape=layer_1_delta.reshape(kernel_output.shape)
        k_update = flattened_input.T.dot(l1d_reshape)
        kernels -= alpha*k_update
        
    test_correct_cnt=0
    
    for i in range(len(test_images)):
        
        layer_0=test_images[i:i+1]
        layer_0=layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0],28,28)
        layer_0.shape
        
        sects=list()
        
    for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
        for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
            sect=get_image_section(layer_0,
                                  row_start,
                                  row_start+kernel_rows,
                                  col_start,
                                  col_start+kernel_cols)
            sects.append(sect)
        expanded_input=np.concatenate(sects,axis=1)
        es=expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input=expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1],-1)
        
        kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
        layer_2 =  np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2)
        test_correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2)==
                                np.argmax(test_labels[i:i+1]))
    if(j % 1 == 0):
        sys.stdout.write("\n"+\
         "I:"+str(j)+ \
         "Test-Acc:"+str(test_correct_cnt/float(len(test_images)))+\
         "Train-Acc:"+str(correct_cnt/float(len(images))))
```

However, I get this error in line 123:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6c33a1c4b65c> in <module>
    121         kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
    122         layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
--> 123         layer_2 =  np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2)
    124         test_correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2)==
    125                                 np.argmax(test_labels[i:i+1]))

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1,400) and (10000,10) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 10000 (dim 0)
```

I have tried to change many areas, but doesn't work. How can I fix this problem? How should I change the dimensions of my matrices? How should I determine the dimensions of my weight matrix?

Comment: how much of this code is yours, and whats borrowed from a poorly documented tutorial?  If you know some numpy basics the error is obvious, but for a poorly explained tutorial, the slightest deviation sends you off into error filled 'woods'.

Comment: yes,sir.i borrowed it from other document.And i tried to change matrix or something relevant,but does't work.How should i change my code

Comment: The error tells us which variables hard the problem, and their respective shapes.  Do you understand why those shapes don't work?  Also do you understand why those variables have those shapes?  Without that basic understanding you can't proceed with any correction(s).